# Tensorflow loss calculation for multiple positive classifications

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function, multiclass-classification

My label looks like this

```
label = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Meaning that classes `1, 4` are present on the matching sample input.

1. How do I create one-hot encoded labels for a label like that?
2. Which loss function is more appropriate for a case like this (sigmoid cross entropy, softmax cross entropy, or sparse softmax cross entropy)?

Comment: You can either use sigmoid cross entropy or softmax cross entropy for the one-hot encoded lables. Sparse softmax cross entropy only allows index labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is not a good reason to create a `one-hot` encoded version of this and if you want to keep the output labels size to be exactly the same, which is `6` in your case, you can't do a `one-hot` encoded version of it.
2. Where `multi-label classification` is to be done, you can not (more appropriately should not) use `softmax` as activation. `Softmax` is good for the cases where only one of the output can be the truth value. So, in your case it is better to use `sigmoid cross-entropy`.